# Which grammar is this?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, regular-expressions

Having the grammar `G = (V,P,S)` with variable `V = {S,A}` over the alphabet `{a,b}` with the rules:

> S->aA
>
> A->Sbb|b

How can i recognize which kind of grammar is this? I think that's not "regular expression" because in the second rule there are 2 letters (bb) instead of one, so i think it's a "context free" grammar. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it is a linear grammar, where every production is of the form $A\to uBv$ where $A,B$ are variables, and $u,v$ are terminal strings. The linear languages are in between the regular and context-free languages.

The power of these grammars is reduced because in every string (sentential from) derived there is (at most) one variable. They are more powerful than right-linear grammars because the terminal strings that are generated during the derivation can appear both left end right from the variable. An example of a linear language that is not regular is $\{a^nb^n \mid n\ge 1\}$.
An example of a language that is context-free, but not linear, is $\{ w\in\{a,b\}^* \mid w \text{ contains the same number of $a$ and $b$}\}$.